# Where does SSAS processing occur

Tags: ssas

If my source data is on Server 1, the cube is on Server 2, and I manually initiate cube/dimension processing in BIDS on my local machine, where exactly does processing occur?

Answer (score 3):

With the traditinal MOLAP storage mode, the query (for raw data) will be executed on Server 1, the aggregation calculations will be done by the server which hosts the SSAS instance (Server 2).

The ROLAP mode will create indexed views on the source system and queries those views, so the 'calculations' are performed by the database engine (Server 1).

With HOLAP mode, it depends on the query since the aggregations are stored in the AS database (calculated by the AS engine while processing), while raw data is accessed from the source system (during a drill-down for example).

Basically you can say: All information stored in the AS database, the calculations are made by the AS engine.

For more information about storage modes see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174915.aspx